# Prolog Clear List of positive elements without using cuts

Tags: list, prolog

I want to clear a list without cutting. I tried:

```
filter([],[]).

filter([H|T],[H|S]) :- 
   H<0,
   filter(T,S).

filter([H|T],S) :- 
   H>=0,
   filter(T,S).
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is what happened when I tried:

```
?- filter([1,0,-6,7,-1],L).

L = [-6,-1]; %false
no

L=[0,-6,-1] %true
```

Comment: Please explain crearly what is your predicate supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
filter([ ],[ ]).
filter([H|T],X) :-
    ( H > 0 -> X = Y ; X = [H|Y] ),
    filter(T,Y).
```

Because the if-then-else construct in Prolog is sometimes described as having a "hidden cut", meaning that Prolog will not retry (backtrack) the logical outcome in the "if" portion of this construct (it commits to the first and only outcome), it's conceivable that your course instructor might object to this solution (even though no actual cut is used).

But your solution is partially wrong.  You lump the zero elements with the positive ones, where your Question's wording suggests only the positive entries need to be "cleared" from the list.

Comment: Thanks you very much. i did it very well!. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, @bubakazouba, for the eagle-eyed catch.